# Update dictionary from two yield functions

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

Say I have two functions, both which `yield` dictionaries:

```
def one_two_three():
    myDict1 = {}
    myList1 = range(1, 4)
    for i in myList1:
        myDict1['number'] = i
        yield myDict1

def four_five_six():
    myDict2 = {}
    myList2 = range(4, 7)
    for i in myList2:
        myDict2['other_number'] = i
        yield myDict2
```

Is there any way to call the two functions and update the dictionaries to return a data structure like so:

```
{'number': 0, 'other_number': 3}
{'number': 1, 'other_number': 4}
{'number': 2, 'other_number': 5}
```

Comment: Your last example is not a single data structure, but three separate dictionaries.  Do you want those three dictionaries in a list, or what?  It seems like you are likely better off just yielding the value (`i`), not the dictionary itself, and then you can create the dictionaries in the code that calls your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but as a better way, you can yield the tuples of your keys and values them `zip` the generators and create the expected dictionaries with a list comprehension:

```
def one_two_three():
    myList1 = range(0, 4)
    for i in myList1:
        yield 'number',i

def four_five_six():
    myList2 = range(3, 6)
    for i in myList2:
        yield 'other_number',i


print [{i:j,k:z} for (i,j),(k,z) in zip(one_two_three(),four_five_six())]
```

output:

```
[{'number': 0, 'other_number': 3},
 {'number': 1, 'other_number': 4},
 {'number': 2, 'other_number': 5}]
```

As a more pythonic way without using generator functions you can zip the range objects and create your dictionaries using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [{'number':i,'other_number':j} for i,j in zip(range(0,4),range(3,6))]
[{'number': 0, 'other_number': 3},
 {'number': 1, 'other_number': 4},
 {'number': 2, 'other_number': 5}]
```